# Connecting with ssh without password

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

I'm trying to connect using ssh from Window's PuTTY client to Debian Lenny machine without entering password.

For this reason I copied content of `\.ssh\id_rsa.pub` file to Debian's  `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. File `authorized_keys` was missing so I have created new one with text editor.

After this procedure I tried to connect, but Debian still asks password. What I do wrong?

UPD.

I added key file to putty:

[image]

But putty not saves file for configuration. Next time I load connection configuration I must set path to private key:

[image]

How to fix that?

Comment: It is not clear what `id_rsa.pub` file you copied. Are you running [Pageant](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/putty-manuals/0.68/Chapter9.html)?

Comment: I have copied `\.ssh\id_rsa.pub` from windows user home directory. It's content starts from `ssh-rsa AAAAB...`

Comment: Did you set the permissions correctly? `chmod 700 ~/.ssh` and `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`? Have you told PuTTY which private key to use?

Comment: @Zwans I was expecting putty knows about my ssh keys. Trying to set file in `Connections->SSH->Auth` but there I can use only some strange `pkk` file. How to ask putty to use file from `\.ssh\` ?

Comment: Debian Lenny reached end of life in 2012! I wouldn't connect to it at **all** if I were you!

Comment: If you have a (Linux/Cygwin) command-line version of `ssh`, you can enable verbose output and have a look at how the key negation goes and why it doesn't accept the key. Possible putty allows this, too?

Comment: @vico pkk files are generated by [PuTTYgen](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/w64/puttygen.exe). You can also [''convert''](https://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-convert-rsa-private-key-to-ppk-allow-putty-ssh-without-password) an existing private key (keys you generate using `ssh-keygen` for example) to .pkk format so PuTTY is able to use it.

Comment: It's ppk not pkk. Private Putty Key. Note that the file contains the public private key pair.

Comment: I added .ppk file to putty, but it not saves in configuration for further usage. More details in UPD

Comment: The place for saving your configuration changes is under "Sessions" at the top of the Category list.  [How to make PuTTY settings persistent?](https://serverfault.com/questions/12295/how-to-make-putty-settings-persistent)